# Would it make sense to use words from other languages such as Latin?

Tags: language

By this I mean, if I used a Latin phrase or used a Latin title for something, would that make sense?
For example, I was thinking of using a Latin title for an in-world book. Or a Latin species scientific names.
Or use the name of some kind of Latin title.
Thanks,

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the Writing substack than this one.  Also, a lot would depend on context and the phrase used.  Could an ordinary reader get the gist, and would it matter?

Comment: An article that might be of interest to you, one about the many names and words that authors have used, and [their linguistic origin](https://thoughtsonfantasy.com/2015/01/21/exotic-names-7-languages-that-inspire-fantasy-authors/).

Comment: Scientific names are **not** Latin. They are Latin-ish, but they are fundamentally language-independent. They do obey a small number of Latin morphological and syntactical rules, and they *may* have a meaning in Latin or in Latinized Greek; but they *do not* have to have a meaning in the classical languages, and even if they do, the classical meaning is irrelevant. For example, the potato is *Solanum tuberosum*, which would mean "humpy night-shade"; monitor lizards belong to the genus *Varanus*, which is an Arabic word, meaningless in Latin or Greek.

Comment: In the game Final Fantasy VII you can order Korean BBQ, and in the more recent remake there are dogs identified as German shepherds; in the game world, of course, there is neither Korea nor Germany. The only decision here is whether you mind some pedantic readers having a short giggle about the apparent inconsistency; everyone else won't notice, and for anyone who does notice (including the pedants), it won't detract from their enjoyment of the story.

Comment: I also think that this question in its current form belongs to the Writing stack since it asks about the craft of writing rather than the world or its elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "make sense"? Make sense in what context?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, if your world is in the right location. You specify medieval in the tags. *(Edit: This question and answer were moved and the tags have changed)*

> **Medieval Latin** was the form of Latin used in Roman Catholic Western Europe during the Middle Ages. In this region it served as the
> primary written language, though local languages were also written to
> varying degrees. Latin functioned as the main medium of scholarly
> exchange, as the liturgical language of the Church, and as the working
> language of science, literature, law, and administration.
>
> Medieval Latin represented a continuation of Classical Latin and Late
> Latin, with enhancements for new concepts as well as for the
> increasing integration of Christianity. Despite some meaningful
> differences from Classical Latin, Medieval writers did not regard it
> as a fundamentally different language.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Latin

Comment: And let's not forget that written Medieval Latin is spelled differently from both Classical Latin and New Latin, uses *a lot* of conventional scribal abbreviations, and employs many uniquely Medieval words or Medieval meanings of classical words. Saying that one knows Latin is generally taken to mean that one can read Classical and New Latin prose; for such a person, reading Medieval Latin requires significant effort, comparable to a Romanian reading Italian or an Englishman reading Middle English.

Answer (score 2):

**This happens all the time in the Harry Potter books**

https://www.wizardingworld.com/features/why-latin-was-so-important-to-the-harry-potter-books

Latin is good for this because it often makes sense to our ears - a lot of English words have Latin roots and if you understand a Romance language there will be more that makes sense.

The other aspect is that Latin was for a long time (and even now) the language of the learned especially as regards medicine.  Latin makes things sound official.  For example "prurigo nodularis", which means itchy bumps.  You the dermatologist could tell someone they have itchy bumps but they might not feel they got their moneys worth since that is what they told when when you walked in.  Pharmacy also uses a lot of Latin which always smells alchemical to me.

So:  good precedent, less to make up, sounds official - you're good!